# Scala: Case class with generic function argument

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following case class.

```
case class CustomAttributeInfo[T,Y](
          attribute:MyAttribute[_],
          fieldName:String, 
          valueParser:T => Y){}
```

The case class takes three values.

The last argument is a function that will parse an input of any type and return the part of the input we wish to keep.

(Imagine, for just one example, I pass in a jsonstring, convert to json object, and extract an Int).

The companion object will supply a range of functions that we can pass to the case class. The one shown here, simply takes the input as a string and returns it as a string (the most simple possible example).

```
object CustomAttributeInfo {

  val simpleString = (s:String) => s
}
```

I create the case class as follows:

`CustomAttributeInfo(MyAttribute(var1, var2), name, CustomAttributeInfo.simpleString)`

Later, I call the function 'valueParser'

`customAttributeInfo.valueParser(k)`

**Compilation error**

> Error:(366, 69) type mismatch;
>    found   : k.type (with underlying type String)
>    required: _$13
>             case Some(info) => Some((info.attribute, info.valueParser(k)))

I am not a generics expert (obviously). I have done some reading, but I have not seen a discussion about a case like this. Any advice and explanation would be most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dmytro was right that a simple example compiled. In my actual codebase code, however, we needed to be specific about the type.

This worked:

```
object CustomAttributeInfo {

  type T = Any

  val simpleString = (s:T) => s.toString
}
```

Comment: 1. You can't extend an `object` in standard Scala (there is a compiler option to allow it); 2. Even if it was a class/trait, you can only add more requirements when overriding a type member, when it's already exactly known it can't be changed.

Comment: Fair enough. I will investigate. If you are correct, I will update

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provide enough information to answer your question.

The following code compiles.

If you still have compile error provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```
  case class MyAttribute[_](var1: Any, var2: Any)

  case class CustomAttributeInfo[T,Y](attribute:MyAttribute[_], fieldName:String, valueParser:T => Y) {}

  object CustomAttributeInfo {

    val simpleString = (s:String) => s
  }

  val var1: Any = ???
  val var2: Any = ???
  val name: String = ???
  val customAttributeInfo = CustomAttributeInfo(MyAttribute(var1, var2), name, CustomAttributeInfo.simpleString)

  val k = "abc"
  customAttributeInfo.valueParser(k)
```

Comment: thanks. 
I just realized that an MCVE does compile and runs. I will debug a little more and then try to update my question. But to be clear, k should be a string, that is the argument for valueParser(), shouldn't it?